# Self-Referencing Foreign Key Select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure:

Region:

- id            (key)
- parent_region (foreign key - references another region)
- name

Assume I have the following 3 rows:

```
[ id, parent_region, name ]
(0, NULL, "USA")
(1, 0, "Georgia")
(2, 1, "Atlanta")
```

I want to be able to select Atlanta, Georgia, USA by querying on the id:

```
SELECT ... 
  FROM region 
 WHERE id = 2
```

...and return the 3 rows.  I'm using Java/JDBC so obviously I could programatically select the 3 rows one by one... but I'm curious if there is a clever SQL way of doing this.

I'm using MySQL but I'd also be curious about an Oracle or Informix solution as well.

Comment: See: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WHERE id = 2`?

Comment: IMHO, [Closure Tables](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html) would be much better solution, instead of trying to cram it all in a single table.

Comment: Do you have an infinite number of levels or is the max 3?

Comment: @BitOff - infinite number of levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have recursive SELECTs, which is too bad for this problem.

The `WITH RECURSIVE` clause was invented for this. This works in PostgreSQL, and something very close or identical in Oracle.

```
WITH RECURSIVE T(id, parent_region, name) AS
 SELECT id, parent_region, name FROM region WHERE id=2
 UNION
 SELECT id, parent_region, name FROM region JOIN T
   ON (region.parent_region = T.id) IS TRUE -- IS TRUE forces T.id NOT NULL
SELECT id, parent_region, name FROM T;
```

(This will loop indefinitely is you have cycles. See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/queries-with.html) for an explanation of how to avoid this.)

Comment: Just to complete the picture: this will work in Firebird, DB2 and SQL Server as well. But unfortunately that won't help the OP

Comment: Ultimately I went with a closure table but i'll mark this as a valid answer/alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select a.name, b.name, c.name 
from region a, region b, region c  
where a.parent_region = b.id and b.parent_region = c.id and a.id = 2;
```

Produced these results

```
+---------+---------+------+
| name    | name    | name |
+---------+---------+------+
| Atlanta | Georgia | USA  |
+---------+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```